# How to recreate this list to normal comma separated?

Tags: jquery

I have the following string

```
w[]=18&w[]=2&w[]=2[]=2
```

I want to create a jQuery function to make it comma separated like that:

```
18,2,2,2
```

Comment: Specifically jQuery? Could probably use plain ol' JS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String#replace` with a regular expression matching any non-digit, and remove the leading comma:

```
var str = "w[]=18&w[]=2&w[]=2[]=2";
str = str.replace(/\D+/g, ',').substring(1);
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/umudap/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/umudap/1/edit)

Comment: I expected to see an `&`, but there is none.

Comment: @AlvinWong: My eyes aren't what they used to be, I just fixed it. :-) The `&` isn't *always* there, either, so I went another way.

Comment: u have two '..' there.. :) :)

Comment: You will probably need `&` because it *is* the separator in a query string.

Comment: @bipen: Thanks. And a *completely* unnecessary `[^\d]` where `\D` will do! Fixed and fixed.

Comment: @AlvinWong: And yet, it's missing from the OP's quoted input (note the final `&w[]=2[]=2` is missing the `&` before the second `[]=`.

Comment: @user1799573: No, it doesn't. See the live example I just added.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**: It is much easier to just use [`substring()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp) and [`split()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp):

```
var myArray = str.substring(4).split("&w[]=");
```

(Assuming that the missing `&w` is a typo!)

- `substring(4)` thows away the first for characters: `w[]=`
- `split()` splits the string into elements using `&w[]=` as separation string.

---

*Old solution:*

Just find the `w[]=` occurrences and replace the occurrences with a `,` using the [`replace()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) function

```
var str="w[]=18&w[]=2&w[]=2[]=2";
var fixedStr=str.replace(/\&/g,",").replace(/\w?\[\]\=/g,"");
```

To convert the string into an array (I suppose you mean 'array' when you say 'list'), you need to [`split()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) it at the `,`s:

```
var myArray = fixedStr.split(",");
```

Comment: Note this will return one redundant leading comma and subsequently a leading empty array cell.

Comment: Oops I did not see the `&`, the missing `w` and forgot about the leading `w[]=`. The updated answer does work. Thanks for noting!

Comment: Note that the `&` is not reliably present in the input, so your `split` won't work.

Comment: The OP states that the `&` is part of the string (s)he wants to parse. Not `&amp;` or something similar (although if it would have been the case, the `split()` call is easily modified)...

Comment: @Veger: Look at the quoted input again. The `&` isn't always there. It is in the first few, but not near the end. (I'm surprised you haven't tried your solutions in the console or something, you would have noticed it...)

Comment: Look at the assumption I wrote: I suspect it is a typo (as the input is probably from a form), if not you are right!

Answer (score 0):

Going the regular expression way, assuming non-numeric keys and numeric values as in the example, I would `match()` all numbers directly. This would return an array containing all numbers matches (not digits) in the string:

```
var query_string  = 'w[]=18&w[]=2&w[]=2[]=2';
var numbers_array = query_string.match(/\d{1,}/g);
```

If you then need a CSV string, you can then `join()` the array values with a `,` separator:

```
var numbers_csv = numbers_array.join(',');
```